# Planck's theory question

Tags: statistical-mechanics, thermal-radiation, approximations

Could you please tell me why [Planck's theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck's_law) ceases to be valid when the sizes of the bodies and/or their separation distances are comparable to, or smaller than, the wavelength.

My professor told me that the wave characteristics of the energy carriers must be taken into account, but I still don't understand it.

Comment: Do you mean quantum mechanics or the black body radiation. I think you are referring to the former one but I'm not sure..

Comment: I mean the black body radiation.

Comment: Plank's law only valid in the limit of large systems,but I don't know why.